# Автономная работа скрипта на unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

При `SetActive` объекта `textScore` перестает работать счетчик. Я бы хотел, чтобы счетчик работал при `SetActive` и если пользователь перешел на другую `Scenes`, то скрипт останавливал свою работу. И даже если при обычном скрытие объекта, то скрипт  `Money` перестает работать [image: скрытие объекта]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Money : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textScore;
    public int score;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints());
    }

    IEnumerator CountPoints()
    {
        while (score < 10000) 
        {
            textScore.text = score.ToString();
            score++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); 
        }
    }
}
```

`SetActive` Я использую в другом скрипте. В этом скрипте, я пытался сделать подобие перехода. То есть, при нажатие кнопки, изначальный объект скрывался и открывался, тот которой привязан к кнопки. Может есть какой то аналог `SetActive` или что похоже по работе?

```js
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Transition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject phone1;
    public GameObject phone2;
    public GameObject phone3;
    public GameObject phone4;

    public Button button1;
    public Button button2;
    public Button button3;
    public Button button4;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        button1.onClick.AddListener(OnButton1Clicked);
        button2.onClick.AddListener(OnButton2Clicked);
        button3.onClick.AddListener(OnButton3Clicked);
        button4.onClick.AddListener(OnButton4Clicked);

        phone1.SetActive(true);
        phone2.SetActive(false);
        phone3.SetActive(false);
        phone4.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnButton1Clicked()
    {
        phone1.SetActive(true);
        phone2.SetActive(false);
        phone3.SetActive(false);
        phone4.SetActive(false);
    }
    void OnButton2Clicked()
    {
        phone1.SetActive(false);
        phone2.SetActive(true);
        phone3.SetActive(false);
        phone4.SetActive(false);
    }
    void OnButton3Clicked()
    {
        phone1.SetActive(false);
        phone2.SetActive(false);
        phone3.SetActive(true);
        phone4.SetActive(false);
    }
    void OnButton4Clicked()
    {
        phone1.SetActive(false);
        phone2.SetActive(false);
        phone3.SetActive(false);
        phone4.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: что SetActive? куда SetActive? это метод, который вы не используете в коде? Расшифруйте пожалуйста вопрос.

Comment: SetActive в False отключает полностью работу скрипта. То есть он делает ровно то для чего он создан, а тебе это не нравится. Ну раз не хочешь что бы счетчик переставал работать не делаешь SetActive False и проблема решена - счетчик будет работать

Comment: добавил значение SetActive  @aepot

Comment: Лучше переоформь вопрос так что бы было понятно что ты хочешь сделать) Потому что то что ты делаешь в принципе делать бессмысленно и оно работает ровно так как и должно работать по коду. Как только ты отключаешь скрипт через сет актив - скрипт перестает работать дальше и последующий код не воспроизводится

Comment: хорошо, правда  я достиг лимит и поэтому смогу задать новый вопрос через неделю @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA

Comment: может есть аналог SetActive?

Comment: тогда лучше просто перередактируй этот вопрос на новый, это тоже нормально. Я в принципе не понимаю чего конкретно ты хочешь достичь поэтому я не знаю какой ответ на "аналог сет актив"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, ты хочешь управлять видимостью объекта на сцене. Можно попробовать использовать компонент `CanvasGroup` у объектов `phone`. Предварительно этот компонент нужно туда повесить.

Код мог бы выглядеть так:

```js
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Transition : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private CanvasGroup _phone1;
    [SerializeField] private CanvasGroup _phone2;
    [SerializeField] private CanvasGroup _phone3;
    [SerializeField] private CanvasGroup _phone4;

    [SerializeField] private Button _button1;
    [SerializeField] private Button _button2;
    [SerializeField] private Button _button3;
    [SerializeField] private Button _button4;

    private List<CanvasGroup> _phones;

    private void Start()
    {
        _button1.onClick.AddListener(delegate { SwitchToPhone(_phone1); });
        _button2.onClick.AddListener(delegate { SwitchToPhone(_phone2); });
        _button3.onClick.AddListener(delegate { SwitchToPhone(_phone3); });
        _button4.onClick.AddListener(delegate { SwitchToPhone(_phone4); });

        _phones = new List<CanvasGroup>
                    {
                        _phone1,
                        _phone2,
                        _phone3,
                        _phone4
                    };


        SwitchToPhone(_phone1);
    }

    private void SetVisible(CanvasGroup obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.blocksRaycasts = value;
        obj.alpha = value ? 1 : 0;
    }

    private void SwitchToPhone(CanvasGroup targetPhone)
    {
        foreach (var phone in _phones)
        {
            if (phone == targetPhone)
                SetVisible(phone, true);
            else
                SetVisible(phone, false);
        }
    }
}
```

---

P.S. Правильнее было бы вместо метода `SetVisible` сделать расширение для `CanvasGroup`, но это уже на твоё усмотрение.

Comment: Я тебе очень благодарен, что ты пытался мне помочь, но все же проблема не была устранена. Во первых не получится заменить  `GameObject` на `CanvasGroup`, так как объект является картинкой и в самой картинке находится элемент `Canvas`. Во вторых у меня проблема в скрипте  `Money`, потому что при скрытие через `inspector` или через скрипт `Transition` перестает работать. Все же спасибо, что попытался