# Как связать переменные в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Всем привет, у меня есть проблемы которые я не могу решить. Я хочу чтобы переменные **`top`** и **`money`** зависели от значение переменной **`sub`**.

Например:
Если переменная `sub` например имеет число **548**, то в переменной `money` пауза в секунду становиться ***0.4f*** `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);` и в переменной `top` пауза в секунду становиться ***4***`yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);`. То есть, **чем больше число в переменной `sub`, тем быстрее идет набор чисел в переменных `top` и `money`**.

Как то так. Вот весь код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text sub;
    public int score;

    public Text money;
    public int score1;

    public Text top;
    public int score2;


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints());
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints1());
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints2());
    }

    IEnumerator CountPoints()
    {
        while (score < 10000) 
        {
            sub.text = score.ToString();
            score++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); 
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CountPoints1()
    {
        while (score1 < 10000) 
        {
            money.text = score1.ToString();
            score1++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); 
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CountPoints2()
    {
        while (score2 > 0)
        {
            top.text = score2.ToString();
            score2--;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Странно, у вас три переменные с похожими именами `score`, `score1`, `score2`, при этом используете вы везде только одну из них `score`, её вы увеличиваете в двух циклах и уменьшаете в одном. И все три текстовые поля у вас - это отражение одной и той же переменной `score`. Будьте внимательнее. И старайтесь не называть переменные похожим образом, вы в них сами путаетесь в итоге.

Comment: `быстрее работают переменные` Что?

Comment: @KOTlK Да это ещё не самое страшное в этом тексте ))  Вернее, тут всё примерно одинаково чудесатое

Comment: Человеческими словми объясните, так как если бы вы были заказчиком и пытались объяснить разработчику, что надо сделать. Без слов "переменные", "зависеть" и "корява".

Comment: [Как сделать автономную работу скрипта на Unity?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1438045/352119)
/
[Автономная работа скрипта на unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1435700/352119)

Comment: Я поправил все свои ошибки

Comment: Не все. В while и в ToString явно тоже должна быть не одна и та же переменная везде

Comment: Теперь точно все ошибки поправил. Да уж не внимательность большая проблема... @CrazyElf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я уже забыл шарп так что пишу псевдокодом:

```
Int sub = 548; 
float topDelay { get { %сюда пишем линейную функцию от sub% }}
float moneyDelay { get { %сюда пишем вторую линейную функцию от sub%  } }
```

как выглядят линейные функции можно взглянуть на [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

и соответственно передаешь их как аргумент `WaitForSeconds(topDelay);`

ну и соответственно никто не знает какую линейную функцию тебе нужно написать потому что только ты знаешь с какой зависимостью ты хочешь получить прирост или падение `topDelay` и `moneyDelay` относительно `sub`